# Dropdown Menu not working after removing .php extension using .htaccess file

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

My drop down menu is not working after removing .php extension using .htaccess. I managed to work with CSS and Pictures buy changing the links to full links but with dropdown menu I don't know where I am lacking.

I get this error in http server : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

My code is below;

```
<div  style="float:right;">
                        <?php  if(!empty($_SESSION['uid'])){?>
                        <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">

                            <i class="services-icon"></i><span class="fa fa-user fa-2x"></span> &nbsp;<br><?php echo $_SESSION['name'];?>
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>
                        <?php } ?>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                                <li><a href="https://via4holiday.com/MyDashboard">Home</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>

                                <li><a href="https://via4holiday.com/logout">Logout</a></li>
                            </ul>
                </div>
```

Comment: Did you google `404`?  It means it can't find the file.  Did you also rename the file itself?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4027458/2181514

Comment: can you explain clearly? whats your problem

Comment: My DropDown Menu is no longer working after removing .php extensions

Comment: freedomn-m I am on PHP not .net

Comment: freedomn-m with links I got the same error I managed to fix it with using full links but with dropdown menu I don't know where to fix